# How to stick table header(thead) on top while scrolling down the table rows with ng zorro?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using ng zorro table https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en and set position: sticky for  tag but them not work.

css

```
.table-fixed thead {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.table-fixed thead th {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

html

```
 template: `
    <nz-table #colSpanTable [nzData]="listOfData" nzBordered class='table-fixed'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th colspan="2">Home phone</th>
          <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of colSpanTable.data; index as i">
          <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>
```

stick table header(thead) on top

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `y` property on the `nzScroll` input parameter.

```
<nz-table #colSpanTable [nzData]="listOfData" nzBordered [nzScroll]="{ y: '240px' }">
```